# (Python Pandas) MemoryError: skiplist failed when using rolling median and apply

Tags: python, pandas, out-of-memory, median

I've just recently upgraded my pandas package to 0.17.1 and now it seems that my code no longer works:

```
HRData["LBrm"] = HRData.groupby("Agroup")["LB"].apply(pd.rolling_median, 3, min_periods=1)
```

This line once computed a rolling median by group but now it produces an error:

> "MemoryError: skiplist_insert failed"

Perhaps you can assist me in solving my problem?

Notes:

1. I'm running Python 3.5
2. Column "LB" is float64
3. HRData is a dataframe with 60 or so columns and 200 000 rows.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx was speeded-up/optimized between pandas 0.16 and 0.17. See https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4095. Please raise the issue at pandas github page